# How to determine if TURN server is being used (WebRTC)?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, turn

I want to gather stats on the number of users having to fallback to TURN servers. Thus is there a way to find if a RTCPeerConnection is using a TURN server instead of "directly" communicating with a remote peer?

I've tried using pc.getStats() but that only gives me an object with a size property.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [getSelectedCandidatePair](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceTransport/getSelectedCandidatePair). This will return the local/remote candidate that is being used. Each candidate will have a type `host`, `srflx`, `prflx` or `relay`. `relay` means it is using TURN.

Make sure to check both candidates. It is possible that both pairs are TURN (or maybe just one)

Comment: getSelectedCandidatePair isn't implemented in Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

the getStats() result is a Javascript Map object. You can iterate it to find what you need. To get the active candidate pair (and then determine its type) it is best to follow the code from [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/) (which works around the quirks of some browsers) and then check whether either the local or remote candidateType is 'relay'.